# If I use a Type Library (.tlb) in a VB6 project, do I need to distribute it with the .exe?

Tags: com, vb6, typelib

If I make use of a Type Library in a VB6 project do I need to distribute the .tlb file (and perhaps even register it?) with the compiled exe on the target computer?

Answer (score 1):

No, **usually** it is only needed if you actually call code that attempts to use the types from the type library. I have found some exceptions, involving using types from the type library to dimension variables. I think it was something like this...

Supposing the type library defines a structure A, and your app contains a procedure like this. If the type library is not registered your app cannot start - an error message is displayed.

```
Sub testSub1(ByRef mybadarray() As A)
```

but this would be OK

```
Sub testSub2()
  Dim ok As A ' OK provided you never actually Call testSub2 at runtime '
```

Comment: I am unclear on what "code uses the type".    So if I DIM a variable as TYPE  or set that variable to a value, is that considered "using" the type?  and in that case, do I need to distribute the .tlb?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/15639/markj  If I can get some clarification on the above question, I can mark your answer Accepted. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I always distribute .TLB file along with .EXE including registration, it helped me to prevent the multiple run-time errors like "Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object".

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. It's only used at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are using multi-threading, i.e. ActiveX EXEs or in-proc with `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` etc. functions.